# I want to display the image data of my td in the show modal when I click on the show button using Javascript and JQuery but path of the src not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I use laravel 8 for my web application. in the project, I use javascript and jquery for displaying data in the show and edit modals. I only use laravel 8 for processing data on server side. the text data works fine, but for the image data, I want to get the src attribute value and set it to the src attribute of the img tag on my show modal based on the nearest img element of the show button that is clicked using javascript and jquery. But I failed to achieve this. I keep getting the error message 404 not found in console of my browser. I have tried using relative path like  my_full_img_path = "../../../public/storage/"+my_img_path; AND my_full_img_path = "{{ asset('storage/"+my_img_path+"') }}"; both did not working....
This is the error message I got : 1 GET [http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%7B%20asset('storage/phone1.jpg')%20%7D%7D](http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%7B%20asset(%27storage/phone1.jpg%27)%20%7D%7D) 404 (Not Found)

This is my show function code :

```
function show(){
    var category_name_td;
    var category_name_value;
    var category_description_td;
    var category_description_value;
    var image_td;
    var image_td_value;
    var my_img_path;
    var my_full_img_path;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','.show1',function(){
            category_name_td = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:nth-child(2)');
            category_name_value = category_name_td.text();
            category_description_td = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(3)");
            category_description_value = category_description_td.text();
            
            image_td = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(4) img");
            image_td_value = image_td.attr("src");
            console.log(image_td_value);
            my_img_path = image_td_value.slice(30,40);
            // my_full_img_path = "../../../public/storage/"+my_img_path;
            my_full_img_path = "{{ asset('storage/"+my_img_path+"') }}";
            console.log(my_full_img_path);
            $("#showmodal").modal('show');
            $("#categoryname").val(category_name_value);
            $("#categorydescription").val(category_description_value);
            $("#categoryimage").attr('src',my_full_img_path);
            // $("#gender").val(gender_td_value);
        })
    })
}
```

This is my index.blade.php code for show modal :

```
 <!-- Show Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="showmodal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="showmodal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="showmodal">List Of Categories</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="categoryname" class="form-label">Category Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="categoryname" class="form-control" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="categorydescription" class="form-label">Category Description</label>
              <input type="text" id="categorydescription" class="form-control" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <img src="" id="categoryimage" width="300" height="200">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my table td code for displaying data and triggers the show button code :

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Category Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Category Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Image</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach($category_data as $mycategory_data)
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $mycategory_data->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $mycategory_data->categoryname }}</td>
            <td>{{ $mycategory_data->description }}</td>
            <td>
                <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$mycategory_data->image) }}" width="100" height="100">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-warning me-2 show1">Show</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary me-2 edit">Edit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger me-2 delete1">Delete</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

These are my script tags below the index.blade.php body :

```
@section('myscript')
<script src="{{ asset('js/myfunction.js') }}"></script>
<script>
        $("table thead tr th:first-of-type").hide();
        $("table tbody tr td:first-of-type").hide();
        $("#formedit div:first-of-type").hide();
        // $("#formedit div:first-of-type").find('label').hide();
        // $("#formedit div:first-of-type").find('input').hide();
        show();
        edit();
        remove();
</script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

`my_full_img_path = "{{ asset('storage/"+my_img_path+"') }}";`

I think this is where it went wrong, cuz the {{ }} is actually rendered by blade when it is returned from the server, not during runtime at client side. Can you try this instead:
`my_full_img_path = "storage/" + my_img_path;`

then when you inspect it should become something like http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/phone1.jpg , where I think this is where you store your image file?